# how do I calculate cutoff frequency from sampling rate and single pole lowpass filter alpha coefficient?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, filtering, esp8266

I've been using some code which implements a low pass filter on audio signal data sampled every 100 **microseconds** (EDIT: i originally mistakenly typed nano) (aka 10Khz) and then subtracts that lowpassed data from the original signal to yield a highpassed signal. If I'm not mistaken, this code is an implementation of the single pole lowpass filter described [here](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/779.php).

My question is **how do i calculate the cutoff frequency this code is giving me?**

EDIT: added declaration of `valueLowpassed`

```
void hw_timer_sample_fn(void) {

  // init this to typical bias level from op amp
  static float valueLowpassed = 555.0f;

  // read a sample from the Analog to Digital Converter (ADC)
  uint16_t adcValue = system_adc_read();

  // single pole, low-pass filter -- what is FREQUENCY?
  valueLowpassed = valueLowpassed + (adcValue - valueLowpassed) / 64.0f;

  // remove lowpassed from original signal
  const float valueHighpassed = adcValue - valueLowpassed;

  // etc. etc. 
}
```

I have a vague sense that if I increase 64.0f, this is making the filter less drastic but its effect is more sluggish and steady -- is this lowering or raising the cutoff frequency? I decrease that number it has a much more active 'correction' of the original signal.

Comment: I would use some existing implementation, for recursive filtering design is complex. Besides, why using subtraction techniques? Is this FFT based?

Comment: In your equation, `64.0f` is `alpha` [per article]. But, the article calculates `alpha` from: `delta_t = t[1]-t[0]; tau = 0.002; alpha = delta_t / tau`. So, that might be a better basis to start with rather than hardwiring it.

Comment: What type is `valueLowpassed`?  Integer or Float?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan it's a static float declared locally to a function. i've edited the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the article, the code for the filter is `y += alpha * (x - y)`, so you are using an alpha of 1.0/64.0 = 0.015625.
- In the article, the equation for alpha is `alpha = 1 - exp(-deltaT/tau)` or, approximately, `alpha ~= deltaT/tau` when `deltaT` is small compared to `tau`. Solving for tau gives `tau = -deltaT/log(1 - alpha)` or, approximately, `tau ~= deltaT/alpha` when `deltaT` is small compared to `alpha`.
- For your signal sampled at 10 kHz, `deltaT = 0.0001`.
- In the article, tau is the reciprocal of the "cutoff frequency". That's bad terminology in the article, since the 3dB-down frequency is actually `1/(2*pi*tau)`. But using the article's definition, the cutoff frequency is `1/tau ~= alpha/deltaT = 0.015625/0.0001 = 156.25 Hz`. The 3dB-down frequency is a factor of `1/(2*pi)` lower, at 24.868 Hz.
- Notice that `deltaT` is, indeed, small compared to `alpha`, so the approximation should be pretty good. Using the more complicated formula, you would get `1/tau = -log(1-alpha)/deltaT = -log(1-0.015625)/0.0001 = 157.48357 Hz`, and the 3dB-down frequency would be 25.064 Hz.
- **Increasing** your constant 64 has the effect of decreasing alpha, which increases tau, which **decreases** the cutoff frequency. So the low-pass filter would filter away more of the signal, while the high-pass filter would let more of the signal through.

Comment: I appreciate your post, and you clarify some things, but another person has said the 3db down frequency is calculated `F = 1/(2*pi*tau)`?

Comment: some sample calculations using another formula someone has suggested: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4QpGSNrpXk/

Comment: You are correct here about the 3dB down frequency, and my post was not clear. The article refers the cutoff frequency as equal to `1/tau`. But that is not the 3dB down frequency, and I'd argue that the article (and my posted answer) is not really correct in using the term cutoff frequency for `1/tau`. The actual 3dB down frequency is, indeed, `1/(2*pi*tau)`. The article itself contains a link to another article that explains this better. Anyway, I'll try to clarify my answer above.

Comment: Your sample calculations at paste.ubuntu.com are incorrect - the formula you evaluate is missing a minus sign in the exponential. Notice that you get negative values for the frequencies, a sure clue that something is wrong. But if you fix the minus sign, you should get correct answers.

Comment: you are correct that the minus sign was missing. Also, I was just using google to perform the log calculations and rather then log-to-base-e, it was returning log10. Updated calculations [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/t4HbB89cX9/).